# Does a linear program always attains its (finite) infimum?

Tags: linear-programming

Consider the following (Lp).
\begin{align}\min&\quad\mathbf{c} \cdot \mathbf{x}\\
\text{s.t. }&\quad A\mathbf{x} \geq \mathbf{b} \\
&\quad\mathbf{x} \geq \mathbf{0}\end{align}

If $S$ is the feasible set of (Lp), Prove that the following definitions are equivalent.

1. (Lp) is unbounded if $\; ∃ \{x^v\}_{v}⊆ S $ $  ;cx^v → −∞ \;$ as $v → ∞.$
2. (Lp) is unbounded if $\; ∀x ∈ S,\; ∃ \,y ∈ S\;;\; c y < cx.$

Proving 1 $\Rightarrow$ 2  is an easy result from the definition of limits.

Proving 2 $\Rightarrow$ 1 is not easy! There is no guarantee that you can find a sequence whose limit goes to $−∞$. The fact that we have a decreasing sequence of $cx$ for $x ∈ S$ does not necessarily imply (1). Maybe this sequence doesn't get less than a specific number, i.e, it has an infimum in $\Bbb R$.

Remark : If all coordinates of $c$ are positive, since we know that $ x \ge 0$ it results that for any $x ∈ S$, $cx \ge 0.$ In this case of course the limit of any such sequence is not $−∞$.

What are your thoughts? Are these 2 definitions really equivalent?

Comment: Use the fact that $S$ is closed.

Comment: Wow, someone downvoted this answer.

Comment: This is not an answer. Its a comment.

Comment: Based on some feedback I got, I moved it to a comment. Just to be clear, I'm saying 2 implies 1, and the key to proving that involves using the fact that $S$ is closed.